# PHP exec - missing output

Tags: php, windows, exec, sox

I am currently trying to get SoX working through PHP. It all works so far, but I don't get the output back. I've already read that one might route stderr also to the output with "2>&1" .. the problem is, this doesn't seem to work on windows machines.

any other ideas?

code is as follows:

```
exec($path2sox . '/sox ' . $cmd . ' 2>&1', $output = array(), $result);
```

whereas the file gets created (so basic sox command is okay, i also tested it exactly the same command in the windows commandline), but neither result nor output give something in return (SoX verbosity is set to 4, which is full output)

I suppose, windows doesnt understand the 2>&1 statement, but how can this be overcome?

P.S: as suggested below, I also tried this

```
$output = array();
echo "Executing: [$path2sox/sox $cmd]";
exec("$path2sox/sox $cmd", $output, $result);
echo "Result: ";
var_dump($result);
echo "\n
Output: ";
var_dump($output);
```

where the output is:

```
Executing: [I:\SoX/sox --guard -V4 "somedirectory/test.wav" --compression "320.2" "somedirectory/test.mp3"]Result: int(0)
```

Output: array(0) {
} File was created properly ...

Comment: Please share the code you're using.

Answer (score 4):

Are you passing the second output array parameter?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

> *output*
>
> If the output argument is present,
> then the specified array will be
> filled with every line of output from
> the command. Trailing whitespace, such
> as \n, is not included in this array.
> Note that if the array already
> contains some elements, exec() will
> append to the end of the array. If you
> do not want the function to append
> elements, call unset() on the array
> before passing it to exec().

Comment: I suspected this is his issue which is why I asked for code. Sorry, I'm out of upvotes for today!

Comment: No big deal, rep doesn't really have a huge meaning to me anymore. ;)

Comment: I think I'd feel the same in your shoes. Over 10x as much rep as me and you've been on the site less time. Nice work :-)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you might be right that windows isn't liking the `2>&1` statement. What do you see when you try:

```
$output = array()
echo "Executing: [$path2sox/sox $cmd]";
exec("$path2sox/sox $cmd", $output, $result);
echo "Result: ";
var_dump($result);
echo "\n<br>Output: ";
var_dump(output);
```

Comment: Since the result was 0, that would *appear* to indicate the call was successful. What happens when you run `I:\SoX/sox --guard -V4 "somedirectory/test.wav" --compression "320.2" "somedirectory/test.mp3"` under the commandline?

Comment: i get the debug output of SoX (about 40 lines) with information about the source file the encoder, etc.

Comment: What happens if you replace `somedirectory/test.wav` and `somedirectory/test.mp3` with absolute paths?

Comment: dude? are you trying to make fun of this? no offense but your answers seem kinda random .. what should change in the output when changing from relative to absolute paths?